# How do I delete a stubborn file in the Bin?

Tags: trash, macos, catalina

I have this file (see attached);
[image: Troublesome file]

And I cannot delete it. it doesn't exist...

I have tried typing `rm` in the prompt then dragging the file on to it, I have gone to the actual location of the file and it's not there, I have deleted .Trash folders left right and center and I still can't find it... I have just run First Aid on ALL the volumes I have and the file still mocks me. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: You have of course tried restarting the machine?

Comment: Just a thought, but is the file open by anything at the moment? In terminal: `lsof tunnelBlick.tblk` should show any processes holding on to the file. If it appears try to force-close those processes.

Comment: When you drag and drop the`tunnelBlick.tblk` file from Finder to Terminal, what is its fully qualified pathname?

Comment: lsof tunnelBlick.tblk states 'no such file or directory' and when I drag and drop I get the following;
`/Users/SHORT-NAME/Library/CloudStorage/iCloud\ Drive/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the file `tunnelBlick.tblk` is in `~/.Trash`, then one sure way of deleting this file is to boot to  **Recovery Mode**, (**⌘R** when restarting the **Mac**), and then in **Terminal** (on the **Utilities** menu)... use the following *command*, e.g.:

```
rm -f /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_Short_Name/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk
```

- The example *command* above assumes the main **Startup** volume is **Macintosh HD**, change as needed.
- The **Your_Short_Name** is that which you normally see in **Finder** as the name on your **Home** folder.

Then type `reboot` and press **enter** to restart the **Mac** back to normal mode boot.

**NOTE:** The `rm` *command*, especially with the `-f` *option* is potentially destructive if the *target* is not properly typed. Make sure the *command* is properly typed before executing. You can also first try without the `-f` *option* and the see if e.g.:

```
ls /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_Short_Name/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk
```

Returns anything, and is so, then use the `-f` *option*.

---

**Update:** Based on the answer to the question I asked in the comment under your question, you would use the following *command* from **Recovery Mode**, (**⌘R** when restarting the **Mac**):

```
rm -f /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Your_Short_Name/Library/CloudStorage/iCloud\ Drive/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk
```

With the same caveats applying:

- The example *command* above assumes the main **Startup** volume is **Macintosh HD**, change as needed.
- The **Your_Short_Name** is that which you normally see in **Finder** as the name on your **Home** folder.

---

Note: You can first try from normal mode:

```
rm -f /Users/Your_Short_Name/Library/CloudStorage/iCloud\ Drive/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk
```

If that doesn't work you can also try prefacing the command with `sudo`; however. if it will not delete from normal mode then boot to recovery mode.

Comment: Here's the weird thing... My Trash as it currently stands...
![My Trash](https://imgur.com/vGIAj2c).

Comment: @Takuhii, See the **Update:** at the end of my answer.

Comment: rm -rf with sudo did it for me, I didn't need to start recovery mode.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is running this following command in Terminal

```
killall 'Finder'
```

Then once Finder quits, in a second or two, Finder should automatically restart.  Then try going back to empty the trash.

If that does not work then I would attempt this...

Try restarting the computer in Safe Mode.

> 1. Start or restart your Mac, then immediately press and hold the Shift key. The Apple logo appears on your display. If you don't see
>      the Apple logo, [learn what to do](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204267).
> 2. Release the Shift key when you see the login window. If your startup disk is encrypted with [FileVault](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204837), you might be asked to log in
>      twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the
>      Finder.
>
> To leave safe mode, restart your Mac without pressing any keys during
>   startup.
>
> Safe mode (sometimes called safe boot) is a way to start up your Mac
>   so that it performs certain checks and prevents some software from
>   automatically loading or opening. Starting your Mac in safe mode does
>   the following:
>
> - Verifies your startup disk and attempts to repair directory issues, if needed
> - Loads only required kernel extensions
> - Prevents startup items and login items from opening automatically
> - Disables user-installed fonts
> - Deletes font caches, kernel cache, and other system cache files

<sup>Source: [Use safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262)</sup>

Once your computer has rebooted into Safe Mode, then go ahead and try to empty your trash.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting in the trash, try putting it into the /tmp/ folder, like so:

```
mv -fv /Users/SHORT-NAME/Library/CloudStorage/iCloud\ Drive/.Trash/tunnelBlick.tblk /tmp/
```

The /tmp/ folder is cleared out on reboot, so that might do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rm -rf folder name with wild card(the path of the file)` not in the root folder. Or write a python script using `glob` library to execute this process. You can add your paths you want to delete whenever you want.